# CircleCI-Slack integration formatting is not working as it used to be

Tags: continuous-integration, slack-api, circleci

After an upgrade to slack api, the formatting of circle-ci messages into slack channels is not working properly. I am trying to see what i can do in the config.yaml file to add some colour to it, i am a novice so thought this would be a small task i could take on from the dev team, but I've hit a roadblock

Is there a better way to format this

```
  "elements": [
                                  {
                                      "type": "button",
                                      "text": {
                                          "type": "plain_text",
                                          "text": "View Job"
                                      },
                                      "url": "${CIRCLE_BUILD_URL}"
                                  }
                              ]
```

Adding emoji: true doesn't really change anything, is there a way to change the formatting of the text and to print out better descriptive messages in a fail and a pas scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use emojis in your build, besides adding `emoji: true` you need to add the emojis at the `text` too. I'll share an example, feel free to edit it.

```
{
   "text":"CircleCI job succeeded!",
   "blocks":[
      {
         "type":"header",
         "text":{
            "type":"plain_text",
            "text":"Deployment Successful! :tada:",
            "emoji":true
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"section",
         "fields":[
            {
               "type":"mrkdwn",
               "text":"*Project*: $CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME"
            },
            {
               "type":"mrkdwn",
               "text":"*When*: $(date +'%m/%d/%Y %T')"
            },
            {
               "type":"mrkdwn",
               "text":"*Tag*: $CIRCLE_TAG"
            }
         ],
         "accessory":{
            "type":"image",
            "image_url":"https://assets.brandfolder.com/otz5mn-bw4j2w-6jzqo8/original/circle-logo-badge-black.png",
            "alt_text":"CircleCI logo"
         }
      },
      {
         "type":"actions",
         "elements":[
            {
               "type":"button",
               "text":{
                  "type":"plain_text",
                  "text":"View Job"
               },
               "url":"${CIRCLE_BUILD_URL}"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

See the first `text` block, there is a `:tada` emoji, also the message is separated into blocks, see the screenshot of this config:
[image: slack]